# Apex Class Test Coverage is failing at a particular line

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

My Apex class test coverage is just reaching 48% and failing at a particular line, not sure why it is happening as I am providing all the data that is necessary. My test class look like below.

```
@isTest
global class CustomerAccountFromRecordComboTest {
    @isTest
    static void CreateTestCustomerAccount() {

        List<Account> updateAccount                 = new List<Account>();
        List<User> updateUser                       = new List<User>();
        List<Record_Combination__c> updateCusAccId  = new List<Record_Combination__c>();


        User so                 = new User();
        so.ProfileId            = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'].Id;
        //so.RoleId               = [SELECT Id FROM Role WHERE Name = 'Sales Team East'].Id;
        so.FirstName            = 'SO';
        so.LastName             = 'user';
        so.Email                = 'puser000@amamamaso.com';
        so.Special_Permissions__c = 'Sales Owner';
        so.Username             = 'puser000@amamama.com' + System.currentTimeMillis();
        so.CompanyName          = 'TEST';
        so.Title                = 'title';
        so.Alias                = 'alias';
        so.FederationIdentifier = 'puser000@amamamaso.com';
        so.TimeZoneSidKey       = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        so.EmailEncodingKey     = 'UTF-8';
        so.LanguageLocaleKey    = 'en_US';
        so.LocaleSidKey         = 'en_US';
        insert so;

        updateUser.add(so);

        User sso                 = new User();
        sso.ProfileId            = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'].Id;
        sso.FirstName            = 'SSO';
        sso.LastName             = 'user';
        sso.Email                = 'puser000@amamamasso.com';
        sso.Special_Permissions__c = 'Sales Owner';
        sso.Username             = 'puser000@amamama.com' + System.currentTimeMillis();
        sso.FederationIdentifier = 'puser000@amamamasso.com';
        sso.CompanyName          = 'TEST';
        sso.Title                = 'title';
        sso.Alias                = 'alias';
        sso.TimeZoneSidKey       = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        sso.EmailEncodingKey     = 'UTF-8';
        sso.LanguageLocaleKey    = 'en_US';
        sso.LocaleSidKey         = 'en_US';
        insert sso;

        updateUser.add(sso);

        User am                 = new User();
        am.ProfileId            = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'].Id;
        am.FirstName            = 'AM';
        am.LastName             = 'user';
        am.Email                = 'puser000@amamamaam.com';
        am.FederationIdentifier = 'puser000@amamamaam.com';
        am.Username             = 'puser000@amamama.com' + System.currentTimeMillis();
        am.CompanyName          = 'TEST';
        am.Title                = 'title';
        am.Alias                = 'alias';
        am.TimeZoneSidKey       = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        am.EmailEncodingKey     = 'UTF-8';
        am.LanguageLocaleKey    = 'en_US';
        am.LocaleSidKey         = 'en_US';
        insert am;

        updateUser.add(am);

        Account acc                    = new Account();
        acc.OwnerId                    = so.Id;
        acc.Name                       = 'Test Account';
        acc.Customer_Success_Manage__c = am.Id;
        acc.netsuite_conn__NetSuite_Id__c = '5678';
        insert acc;

        updateAccount.add(acc);

        Account agc = new Account();
        agc.Name    = 'Test Agency';
        agc.netsuite_conn__NetSuite_Id__c = '4769';
        insert agc;

        updateAccount.add(agc);

        Contact con   = new Contact();
        con.FirstName = 'Test';
        con.LastName  = 'Contact';
        con.Phone     = '9930039303';
        con.AccountId = acc.Id;
        insert con;

        acc.OB_Customer_Contact__c = con.Id;
        // acc.Billing_Notes__c       = 'Test account billing notes';
        update acc;

        agc.OB_Customer_Contact__c = con.Id;
        // agc.Billing_Notes__c       = 'Test agency billing notes';
        update agc;

        Relationship__c rel = new Relationship__c();
        rel.Account_Client__c = acc.Id;
        rel.Agency__c = agc.Id;
        rel.Relationship_Type__c = 'Agency Client';
        rel.Relationship_Status__c = 'Active';
        insert rel;

        Record_Combination__c recCombo = new Record_Combination__c();
        recCombo.Client__c = acc.Id;
        recCombo.Agency__c = agc.Id;
        recCombo.Client_Agency_Relationship__c = rel.Id;
        recCombo.Primary_Sales_Owner__c = so.Id;
        recCombo.Secondary_Sales_Owner__c = sso.Id;
        recCombo.Primary_Sales_Owner_Split_PCT__c = 70.0;
        recCombo.Secondary_Sales_Owner_Split_PCT__c = 30.0;
        recCombo.Record_Combination_Effective_Date__c = Date.today();
        //recCombo.Primary_Sales_Owner_Effective_Date__c = Date.today();
        recCombo.Customer_Success_Manager__c = am.Id;
        recCombo.Combination_Status__c = 'Proposed';
        insert recCombo;

        recCombo.Combination_Status__c = 'Active';
        update recCombo;
        updateCusAccId.add(recCombo);
    }
}
```

And here is the SFDC_DataObject's CustomerObject class for your reference, which I am using as a wrapper class for the code that you can see in the image below.

```
public class CustomerObject {
        public Integer parentId;
        public String  sfCustomerId; 
        public String  companyName;
        public String  customerEmail;
        public String  billingEmail;
        public String  billingPhone;
        public String  billingName;
        public String  billingNotes;
        public String  nsCustomerId;

        public CustomerObject() {}

        public CustomerObject(Integer parentId, String sfCustomerId, String companyName, String customerEmail, String billingEmail, String billingPhone, String billingName, String billingNotes, String nsCustomerId)
        {
            this.parentId      = parentId;
            this.sfCustomerId  = sfCustomerId;
            this.companyName   = companyName;
            this.customerEmail = customerEmail;
            this.billingEmail  = billingEmail;
            this.billingPhone  = billingPhone;
            this.billingName   = billingName;
            this.billingNotes  = billingNotes;
            this.nsCustomerId  = nsCustomerId;
        }
    }
```

I am adding an image below to show the line where the coverage of my apex class is halting. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong, and please let me know if you need any more details. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please, look at `SFDC_DataObject` class and find the exact line, where the code fails. If there is no FATAL_ERROR in logs after running test, then it will be seen with test coverage.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova Thanks for the response. I Just checked the Wrapper class too as you had mentioned but couldn't find any difference there. I have edited the question and added that too for your reference. Will enable debug logs and check if I can find anything. Please let me know if you think I should be changing something or looking into something particularly.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova After enabling the debug logs I was able to find out that I had added the field netsuite_conn__NetSuite_Id__c without querying it. After adding that to the query I was able to get the necessary coverage. Thank you for the help, if you can add your comment as answer, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found from debug logs, the problem was with netsuite_conn__NetSuite_Id__c field, that was used without querying it in the first place.

However, for the general usefulness of this question for the community, I want to add some tips:

- Check DEBUG_LOG when running your tests.
- If log is not available, you can detect the problem place via code coverage, where it stops unpredictably.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @AkshayVasu You are welcome)